# htaccess - conditional rewrite and expire

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cache-control, mod-expires

*Hey there!*

I have a folder `/static` in my Apache 2.x server webroot. If a request matches

```
/static/<somename like [\S-_]+>.(png|jpg|css|js)/\d{8,15}
```

for example

```
/static/bg.jpg/1335455634
```

I want two things:

- url shall be rewritten to `/static/bg.jpg` (getting rid of the timestamp)
- it shall become a [never-expire](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) ('expires 2030, max-age=290304000, public cache, ...)

If the request does not match, the request and it's headers should be as normal, no rewrite. Ideally, any request outside /static/* should not be affected (though «coincidental trailing timetamps» should be rare...)

I have nothing but trouble with FilesMatch / RewriteCond, so I rather not post my poor attempts... (Rewrite in genereal is enabled on my machine, and I do possess the rights to send cache-related headers)

***Dankeschön!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^static/([^/]+\.(png|jpg|css|js))x?/\d{8,15}$ /static/$1 [NC,L]

<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|css|js)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you. I *will* look and test it. I beg your patience for another 2-3 days.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. By the way, this is a very useful tool for testing htaccess rules - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Thank you. Your Solution, respectively both your solutions work. One Thing appears impossible though: That non-rewritten-files get a regular expiry, and only rewritten files get the never-expire. FilesMatch appears to care only about the finally-opened File, nothing that happens before. Regardless if placed above or below the rewrite rule. In other words, all jpgs, pngs now become never-expires. So even if I go for `static/simple.jpgx/123456789` (that's why I temporarily stuck in the `x?`), it gets matched.

Comment: The other way round, appending `/\d{8,15}` to the filematch is of no use (because no finally-opened file matches). The only way would probably be rewrite all regular (non-timestamp) files to a tunnel-ish `static/download.php?%1`. That would not be caught by Filesmatch (because ultimately it's .php)...

Comment: ... or an educational `RewriteRule ^static/([^/]+\.(png|jpg|css|js))$ /static/dontdothis.php?$1 [NC,L]` :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^static/([^.]+\.(png|jpe?g|css|js))/\d{8,15}$ static/$1 [L,R,NC]

# now set expire date to today + 1 year
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 years" 
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 years" 
</IfModule>
```

I have chosen `iccess plus 1 years` for **never-expires** because I found this on web:

> "To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an
> Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is
> sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one
> year in the future."
>
> **From the HTTP 1.1 RFC**

Comment: Yes you can add `.gif` also.